Handle multiple clients in a browser terminal that is created by xtermjs
My browser terminal application runs without problem while it is used by a single client but when another client connects to it and tries to use the same terminal is shown to the new client. Also when i open it in another tab it shows the same terminal too. Defining seperate terminals in xtermjs like termA and termB is not viable since number of clients is not certain. The application runs with django in backend. Xtermjs is only used for visualization and getting user input. A pseudo terminal and bash process handles terminal logic in the django. My first approach was to implement multiprocessing in the django but i failed to achieve it. I am open to different approaches to solve this issue.
views.py:
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
import socketio
import pty
import select
import subprocess
import struct
import fcntl
import termios
import signal
import eventlet    

async_mode = "eventlet"
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)

fd = None
child_pid = None

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def set_winsize(fd, row, col, xpix=0, ypix=0):
    winsize = struct.pack("HHHH", row, col, xpix, ypix)
    fcntl.ioctl(fd, termios.TIOCSWINSZ, winsize)


def read_and_forward_pty_output():
    global fd
    max_read_bytes = 1024 * 20
    while True:
        sio.sleep(0.01)
        if fd:
            timeout_sec = 0
            (data_ready, _, _) = select.select([fd], [], [], timeout_sec)
            if data_ready:
                output = os.read(fd, max_read_bytes).decode()
                sio.emit("pty_output", {"output": output})
        else:
            print("process killed")
            return


@sio.event
def resize(sid, message):
    if fd:
        set_winsize(fd, message["rows"], message["cols"])
    

@sio.event
def pty_input(sid, message):
    if fd:
        os.write(fd, message["input"].encode())


@sio.event
def disconnect_request(sid):
    sio.disconnect(sid)


@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    global fd
    global child_pid

    if child_pid:
        os.write(fd, "\n".encode())
        return

    (child_pid, fd) = pty.fork()

    if child_pid == 0:
        subprocess.run("clear")
        subprocess.run('bash')

    else:
        sio.start_background_task(target=read_and_forward_pty_output)


@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):

    global fd
    global child_pid

    os.kill(child_pid,signal.SIGKILL)
    os.wait()

    fd = None
    child_pid = None
    print('Client disconnected')

index.html:
<html>

<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/xterm@5.2.1/css/xterm.css" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xterm@5.2.1/lib/xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xterm-addon-fit@0.7.0/lib/xterm-addon-fit.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.4.0/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main" style="margin-left: 5%; position:sticky;">

        <div style="background: white; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-top:1%;">
            <span>Status: <span style="font-size: small; background-color: #d9ff00;"
                    id="status">connecting...</span></span>
            <button id="button" ; type="button" ; onclick="myFunction()" ; style="padding:0.2%;">Connect</button>
        </div>

        <div style=" width: 98%; height:50%;" id="terminal"></div>

    </div>

    <script>

        var socket = io.connect({ transports: ["websocket", "polling"], autoConnect: false });

        const status = document.getElementById("status")
        const button = document.getElementById("button")
        const fit = new FitAddon.FitAddon();

        // Clear sessionStorage when the page is reloaded or closed
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            sessionStorage.clear();
        });

        var term = new Terminal({
            cursorBlink: true,
        });

        term.loadAddon(fit);
        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
        fit.fit();


        term.onKey(e => {
            socket.emit("pty_input", { "input": e.key });
        })

        socket.on("pty_output", function (output) {
            term.write(output["output"]);
        })

        socket.on("connect", () => {
            status.innerHTML = '<span style="background-color: lightgreen;">connected</span>'
            resize()
            button.innerHTML = 'Disconnect'
        })

        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            status.innerHTML = '<span style="background-color: #ff8383;">disconnected</span>'
            button.innerHTML = 'Connect'
        })

        function myFunction() {
            if (button.innerHTML == 'Connect') {
                console.log("conn req")
                socket.connect();
            }

            else if (button.innerHTML == "Disconnect") {
                socket.emit("disconnect_request")
            }
        }

        function resize() {
            console.log("resized")
            fit.fit()
            socket.emit("resize", { "cols": term.cols, "rows": term.rows })
        }
        window.onresize = function () {
            console.log("size changed")
        }
        window.onresize = resize
        window.onload = resize


    </script>
</body>

</html>


Your code is broken regarding the pty master fd, as it always refers to global fd. Whenever connect is called, fork will create a new pty and overwrite the previous one. What you need instead is a data structure holding the fd per session id, and read/write from that fd for a given session id (caution here with multithread approaches and atomic access to that data structure)
Btw this is not a terminal question, but a question regarding servers and how to store/handle multiple connections and its data.

@jerch thanks for your comment. i know that global fd approach must be changed. i need a proper approach to distinguish separate terminals and operate them.

Well you'd have to create something like a session id on terminal spawn, and pass it along with requests against read/write. In these functions simply map the session id back to the terminal. Ideally that session id cannot be guessed easily for security reasons (so dont use simple autoincrementing integers).

i managed to assign an uuid to each session but i am still struggling to forward these terminals to separate bash processes. any suggestions? @jerch

You need to create a PTY per terminal session uuid, and strictly route the IO to the correct PTY. Effectively you'd have as many PTYs open as there are terminals open on all pages (makes it a terminal server).

i assigned child_pid and fd for each terminal according to their uuid using pty.fork(). it doesnt separate bash processes for each terminal. can you elaborate further? @jerch

I think you are better off with encapsulating the pty stuff first in a class, as it makes things more comprehensible (taken from my own django based terminal server impl):
import os
from select import select
from pty import fork
from termios import TIOCSWINSZ, TIOCGWINSZ
from struct import pack, unpack
from fcntl import ioctl
from os import execl, closerange
from time import sleep, time

# struct winsize {
#     unsigned short ws_row;
#     unsigned short ws_col;
#     unsigned short ws_xpixel;   /* unused */
#     unsigned short ws_ypixel;   /* unused */
# };
DEFAULT_SIZE = (24, 80, 0, 0)
DEFAULT_CMD = ['/usr/bin/ssh', '/usr/bin/ssh', 'localhost']
DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'UTF-8'


class PtyTerminal:
    """
    Spawn a new PTY terminal with ``cmd`` as the first child process.
    The PID of the child process is stored as ``child``.
    """
    def __init__(self, cmd=None, size=None):
        # TODO: set env and cwd..., eg. use different exec*
        self.master = None
        self.child = None
        child, master = fork()
        if child == 0:
            closerange(3, 255)
            execl(*(cmd or DEFAULT_CMD))
        self.child = child
        self.master = master
        self._size = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.size = size or DEFAULT_SIZE
        self.exit_state = None

    @property
    def size(self):
        if self.master:
            return self._size
        return (0, 0, 0, 0)

    @size.setter
    def size(self, value):
        if self.master and value != self._size:
            ioctl(self.master, TIOCSWINSZ, pack('HHHH', *value))
            self._size = unpack('HHHH', ioctl(self.master, TIOCGWINSZ, '12345678'))

    def close(self):
        """
        Close the master fd, ending the PTY session.
        Normally this signals a SIGHUP to PTY children processes cleaning them up.
        In case a PTY child got stuck you might have more success with
        ``os.kill(pid, sig)``. PtyTerminal stores the PID of the first child as ``child``.
        """
        if self.master:
            os.close(self.master)
            self.master = None
        if self.child:
            self.wait_child()

    @property
    def is_closed(self):
        return not self.master

    def has_read_data(self):
        if self.master:
            rd_lst, _, _ = select([self.master], [], [], 0)
            return bool(rd_lst)
        return False

    def read(self, length=4096, timeout=None):
        """
        Attempt to read from the PTY.
        Might raise an OSError if all slave ends got closed.
        """
        if self.master:
            try:
                rd_lst, _, _ = select([self.master], [], [], timeout)
                return os.read(self.master, length) if rd_lst else b''
            except OSError:
                self.wait_child()
                if not self.child:
                    self.close()
        return b''

    def write(self, data, encoding=None):
        if not self.master or not data:
            return
        if isinstance(data, str):
            data = data.encode(encoding or DEFAULT_ENCODING)
        length = len(data)
        sent = 0
        while sent < length:
            sent += os.write(self.master, data[sent:])

    def wait_child(self):
        res = None
        if self.child:
            try:
                res = os.waitpid(self.child, os.WNOHANG)
                pid, wstate = res
                if pid == self.child:
                    self.child = None
                    self.exit_state = os.waitstatus_to_exitcode(wstate)
            except ChildProcessError:
                self.child = None
        return res

    def force_kill_close(self):
        if self.child:
            os.kill(self.child, 9)
            sleep(1)
            self.wait_child()
            if self.exit_state != -9:
                os.kill(self.child, 15)
                sleep(1)
                self.wait_child()
                if self.exit_state not in (-9, -15):
                    print(f'Warning: force_kill of child PID {self.child} failed!')
                    return
            self.child = None
        self.close()
        return self.exit_state

This basically gives you a convenient class for PTY interactions like spawn, read/write, size and (force) kill.
With that out of the way, you now can set up the separation of terminal sessions, e.g. in your views.py. The following is for "classical" long-polling (have never worked with SocketIO):
from pty_terminal import PtyTerminal
from django.http import HttpResponse

terminals = {}

def create(request):
    # do some sort of auth/permission checks here,
    # otherwise anyone can flood your server with PTYs
    ...
    token = uuid4().hex
    terminal = PtyTerminal()
    terminals[token] = terminal
    return HttpResponse(token, content_type='text/plain')

def read(request, token):
    # auth/permission checks again
    ...
    terminal = terminals[token]
    read_data = terminal.read(length=65536, timeout=10)
    return HttpResponse(read_data, content_type='application/octet-stream')

def write(request, token):
    # auth/permission checks again
    ...
    terminal = terminals[token]
    terminal.write(request.body)
    return HttpResponse('')

def resize(request, token):
    # likewise as above
    ...

So this is the basic scheme doing it with long-polling. There are a few things missing, like a cleanup from time to time to get rid of stale terminals, a proper handling on when the PTY slave side finally got closed or some thread mutexes (remember - view handlers are most likely running in a multi-thread context, depending on your HTML server setup).
For a SocketIO based approach things prolly should be done slightly different, but I don't know enough about their process/thread model underneath to tell whats better here. The scheme above is also quite heavy on kernel ressources (lots of context switches due to isolated select & read/write calls for every single terminal), so there is much room for improvement, like not using long-polling in the first place but websockets for better overall performance.
